# How to get data from a form written directly in the template not in forms.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a page with images and I want to be able to delete some of them so I wrote this form:

```
<form method="post">
    {% for img in images %}
    <img src={{img.image.url}}>
    <input type="checkbox" id={{img.id}} value={{img.id}}>
    {% endfor %}
    
    <button type="submit">DELETE</button>
</form>
```

and this the views.py:

```
def lemqes(request, iid):
    images = IMAGE.objects.filter(id=iid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         #how can I continue to delete multiple images

    return render(request, 'del.html', {'images' : images})
```

EDIT: when I add the name inside the input in html like `<input type="checkbox" id={{img.id}} value={{img.id}} name='dadata'>` and in the views.py I added `print(request.POST.get('dadata'))` it only printed the first value, so my question how to to get all the values checked?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get values by name because every checkbox contains the same name.

you need to call script while any checkbox gets clicked.
get its value and store it in a list.
every time list gets updated then send this list into hidden input of the form.
you can get a list of all checkboxes while submitting the form

or you can refer to this link
[get group of checkboxes](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/same-name-group.php)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, I replaced the checkbox with a button, and when I click the button the image id gets stored in a hidden input attribute and then in the views.py I get the data of that input